# Node.js : How to export data from mongodb and then import the data into mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

I want to export data from mongodb and then import the data into mysql using node.js,

I use the two packages `mongodb` and `mysql` to establish database connections.

`mongodb`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb
`mysql`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

This is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/05todd72/

in the demo, `mondodb` could make data for test successfully.

**Qusetion:**
How to get the data form mongodb and then insert them into mysql?

**update:**
the data that I will export is simple:

```
{"id":"1","title":"foo","content":"foo bar"}
{"id":"1","title":"hello","content":"hello world"}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy task. You are not going to get a complete answer here on StackOverflow because it depends almost completely on your data and it's structure.

Basically, what you're asking is how to map data from your MongoDB database to your MySQL database. Remember that these are two databases that are organized around completely different principles:

- MongoDB is a document database, best suited to storing structured documents that do not rely heavily on relationships between pieces of data.
- MySQL is a relational database arranged around tables of data with important relationships between the rows in those tables.

For example, MongoDB might store something like this as a single document;

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Doe',
    messages: [
        { id: 42, message: 'Hello!', timestamp: '2017-08-29' },
        { id: 43, message: 'Another message', timestamp: '2017-08-29' },
        { id: 44, message: 'Goodbye!', timestamp: '2017-08-29' },
    ],
}
```

MongoDB would store this as a single record (document) and you would retrieve, update, etc. the whole thing as a unit.

MySQL, on the other hand, would store this data in a set of tables, probably one for the user ('John Doe') and one for messages, with a relationship between the two based on the unique ID values for each row.

In order to translate your Mongo data to MySQL, you will have to figure out how the data is going to be stored in the MySQL database and write code that will translate each Mongo document into a series of inserts into the tables involved.

Comment: Try developing your database scheme & writing your code. If you run into problems, post a new question.